# Ubuntu Studio: HP Laptop does not boot anymore after patch installation

Tags: boot, uefi, hp

When turning on the Laptop, the initial screen with the HP Logo (with the message press Esc for setup) will go into a loop. After the timeout for entering the Bios setup, it reset the system and it start over again. The System will not boot the EFI Partition.
My workaround is to press F9 for Boot device, choose Ubuntu EFI and it start up without an issue.
There is only Ubuntu Studio installed, no other System beside.
This happen after a patch update, but I can't make it which one it was, but somewhere after Summer. I hope that this would be fixed with an upcoming patch, but it wasn't.

System: HP Elitebook 8470p, Ubuntu Studio 22.04.1 LTS.

[F9 Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wY7RN.jpg)

[F10 Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9AGW.jpg)

Edit:
The EFI Partition looks like this:

```
root@8470p:/boot/efi/EFI# ll
total 20
drwx------ 5 root root 4096 Nov 18 09:50 ./
drwx------ 3 root root 4096 Jan  1  1970 ../
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Nov 11 10:28 BOOT/
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Apr  6  2022 BOOT_bak/
drwx------ 2 root root 4096 Apr  6  2022 ubuntu/
root@8470p:/boot/efi/EFI# ll ubuntu/
total 3496
drwx------ 2 root root    4096 Apr  6  2022 ./
drwx------ 5 root root    4096 Nov 18 09:50 ../
-rwx------ 1 root root     108 Nov 11 10:28 BOOTX64.CSV*
-rwx------ 1 root root     126 Nov 11 10:28 grub.cfg*
-rwx------ 1 root root 1742728 Nov 11 10:28 grubx64.efi*
-rwx------ 1 root root  856232 Nov 11 10:28 mmx64.efi*
-rwx------ 1 root root  955656 Nov 11 10:28 shimx64.efi*
root@8470p:/boot/efi/EFI# ll BOOT/
total 3580
drwx------ 2 root root    4096 Nov 11 10:28 ./
drwx------ 5 root root    4096 Nov 18 09:50 ../
-rwx------ 1 root root     108 Apr 21  2022 BOOTX64.CSV*
-rwx------ 1 root root  955656 Nov 11 10:28 bootx64.efi*
-rwx------ 1 root root   85672 Nov 11 10:28 fbx64.efi*
-rwx------ 1 root root     126 Apr 21  2022 grub.cfg*
-rwx------ 1 root root 1742728 Apr 21  2022 grubx64.efi*
-rwx------ 1 root root  856232 Nov 11 10:28 mmx64.efi*
root@8470p:/boot/efi/EFI# ll BOOT_bak/
total 1868
drwx------ 2 root root   4096 Apr  6  2022 ./
drwx------ 5 root root   4096 Nov 18 09:50 ../
-rwx------ 1 root root 955656 Apr 19  2022 BOOTX64.EFI*
-rwx------ 1 root root  85672 Apr 19  2022 fbx64.efi*
-rwx------ 1 root root 856232 Apr 19  2022 mmx64.efi*
root@8470p:/boot/efi/EFI#
```

I am not fimilar with this. But If i compare the dates of the files, It seems that something is wrong...

Comment: You may have had a firmware update that reset its settings and it's now trying to boot some non-working entry. But in any case, if you can boot Ubuntu successfully with the boot override menu (F9) then you must be able to select the same boot and set it as default as it was before in UEFI settings (F10) > Boot. Please check before any further troubleshooting.

Comment: With F10 you come Into BIOS setting. There I cannot specify Ubuntu. Only OS Boot Manager or other devices are available.

Comment: What you call BIOS is UEFI since more than decade ago. In the Boot menu you must have the exact same list that you see with F9 in "OS Selection" or similar, end of story.

Comment: Not my end of Story, I attached 2 pictures in the main descritption above. One is the F9 Menu and the Boot Order from F10. You do not see Ubuntu in the F10's Boot Order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by workaround adding a custom boot option
add a custom boot \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
Move the custom boot to the top of the boot order